# Match Outer Div height to inner div list items with Flex display

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a navigation links with text inside in which I want the Div box height to match that of my outer navigation container.

It seem the div box are dependent on font size. I also tried using px or em sizing on the height of the box but its not dynamic as I may want to change font-size. [image: navigation bar example]

I have read over the [Flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but it hasn't provided me any luck as I have seen you can try align-items stretch to fit the outer later but with no luck. or flex-grow but again not what I wanted.

I think it has something to do with using list as I can get it to work using a regular text box div. Also read something about how float items don't have height and it cause them to behave differently so i'm not sure if it applies to flex box.

Thanks an help is appreciated.

HTML code

```
  <div class="navbar">
    <div id="name">
      <span id="coname">Raul Co</span><span id=lname>rrea</span>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul id="menuList">
        <li><a class="active" href="">Mi Casa</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Cooking</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

CSS Code

```
*{margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
  background-color: #908070;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}
#name{
  float: left;
}
#coname {
  color: #F58F7C;
}
#lname{
  color: #99B3FF;
}
nav{
  flex-grow: 1;/*flex:1*/
  text-align: right;
  border: 0.5px solid blue;
}

nav ul li{
display:inline-flex;
font-size: 0.5em;
flex-grow: 1;
border: 0.5px dashed red;
}

/*What I believe I need to fix*/
/*nav ul li a{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  background-size: cover;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #707090;
  border: 1px solid blue;

} */


nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #709090;
  color: #E2EFDE;
}

nav ul li a.active{
  background-color: #707090;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What made it work in the end was not assuming that child element get parents parents parameters.

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container{
  background-color: #908070;
  font-size: 1.75em;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;/* flex and center used if want to make nav height bigger while have it center */
  height: 1.2em; /* dependent on .container font-size */
}
#name{
  /* font-family: "Roboto Slab"; */
  float: left;
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
}
#coname {
  color: #F58F7C;
}
#lname{
  color: #99B3FF;
}
#menu{
  display:none;
}
nav{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  /* height: 100%; */
  flex-grow: 1;/*flex:1*/
}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
}
nav ul li{
display:flex;
}
nav ul li a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 0.65em;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #707090;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: #709090;
  color: #E2EFDE;
}
nav ul li a.active{
  background-color: #707090;
  color: white;
}
```